# How to check Referral URL when HTTP_REFERER is NULL?

Tags: php, curl, http-referer

I am building an API and intend to allow API calls from a particular domain. I am using ´curl´ operator to make the API call without setting the header :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
```

So, when I check $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], it is ´NULL´

Now, how to check in PHP whether the call is made from a particular domain ?

Thanks

Comment: It is (permanently mis)spelled as `HTTP_REFERER`

Answer (score 1):

You must check if particular domain stands in DNS for `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

```
<?php
$ip = gethostbyname('www.example.com');
$valid_call = $ip == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ? true : false;
```

Remember, never trust HTTP headers. They may be manipulated while IP may not.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to pass the REFERER in headers with cURL,

I. Manualy **CURLOPT_REFERER**

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://example.com');
```

II. Automaticaly
or use **CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER**

> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);

see the [cURL setopt docuemntation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)